# Why does this cube in openGL rotate differently when using a perspective matrix?

Tags: c, opengl, matrix, graphics, glm-math

I was just getting into OpenGL and learning about projection matrices using cglm (math library) and glfw. I have 3 matrices : model, view, and projection. In the render loop

```
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
    /* Render here */
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glm_rotate(model, 0.001f, (vec3) { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f });
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, model);
    glBindVertexArray(vao1);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 12, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
    /* Swap front and back buffers */
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    /* Poll for and process events */
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

I am rotating my model about the y-axis, and it rotates about the y axis just fine. But then I add a projection matrix and instead of rotating, it just moves around. Here is a gif of it https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KZso.jpg

```
glm_perspective(0.785f, 740 / 580, 0.0f, 100.0f, projection);
```

Why is this happening? Shouldn't it just look farther away?
This is my vertex shader

```
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) in vec4 InPos;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main() {
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * InPos;
};
```

And here are my vertexes and indices:

```
float triangle1[] = {
    //Coordinates x y z
    0.9f, -0.5f, -5.0f,
   -0.5f, -0.5f, -5.0f,
   -0.5f,  0.5f, -5.0f,
    0.0f,  0.0f, -4.0f
};

unsigned int indices[] = {
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 0, 3,
    1, 2, 3,
    1, 3, 0
};
```

the view matrix is just an identity matrix.

EDIT : the code initializing matrixes

```
mat4 model = GLM_MAT4_IDENTITY_INIT, view = GLM_MAT4_IDENTITY_INIT, projection = GLM_MAT4_IDENTITY_INIT;
glm_perspective(0.785f, 740 / 580, 1.0f, 100.0f, projection);
unsigned int modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "model");
glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, model);
unsigned int viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "view");
glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, view);
unsigned int projectionLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "projection");
glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, projection);
glClearColor(0.5f, 0.1f, 0.9f, 1.0f);
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

/* Loop until the user closes the window */
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
      ....
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue seems to be the line

> ```c
> glm_perspective(0.785f, 740 / 580, 0.0f, 100.0f, projection);
> ```

the projection matrix defines a 3 dimensional space (clip space) which is projected on the 2 dimensional viewport. At [Perspective projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection), this space is a frustum ([Viewing frustum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum)).

In your example the near plane is 0.0. That causes an undefined behavior. The value for the near plane and the far plane have to be greater than 0.0 and the far plane has to be greater then the near plane:

```
0 < near < far
```

When you draw the geometry, the you have to ensure, that the geometry is in between then near and the far plane (in clip space respectively in the viewing volume), else the geometry is clipped.

[image]

Change the value for the near plane. For instance:

```c
glm_perspective(0.785f, 740.0f / 580.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f, projection);
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I tried your suggestion and tried values 0.1f --> 1.0f, but it still had the exact same behaviour. I added my matrix code to the question in case there's something wrong there. Any ideas? Thanks.